# Timeout when using WCF host on IIS 6

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a problem regarding hosting of a WCF service on IIS 6.

My host is fine, I assume, and I can connect to it from a normal app, and get my stuff done.
But now I want to stress test the service and I wanna do it from a web client, normal aspx page calling the wcf service with a click of a button, and being able to scale it up and down.

My problem is that I am getting a timeout when connecting/retrieving data from the service.
I think it could have something to do with authentication, but I'm not really sure...

I am using WShttpbindings on the server and on my normal clients... and I call the WCF service as a service reference directly in my web test project!

thanks in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems before, I had to ensure that I closed the factory as soon as I'd finished with it. You can increase the number of allowed connection to the service too, but you should make sure that you close the factory the moment you've finished with it.

As always, check out **Nicholas Allen's blog** for all things WCF: http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2007/12/28/controlling-http-connection-limits.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing the services and read the generated logs with the [SvcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few posts that explain why this happens in regard to [IDisposable](http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx) and
[Throttling](http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Configuring+Performance+Options+-+WCF+Gotcha+3.aspx).